# How can I add button to top right corner of a Dialog In libgdx?

Tags: layout, libgdx

I want to add close button to top right corner of a dialog box.

I tried using setbounds with addactor and just add and setposition with setsize and addactor, but nothing works. I know that dialog works with table layout, it has a table for content and for buttons. I don't want to use this layout and put the button outside this layout like on the border of the dialog.

How can I do it?

This is how it should be:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution I could come up with now, is to use negative padding for your button to move it "outside" of it's cell.

```
Button closeButton = new TextButton("X", skin, "default");
getTitleTable().add(closeButton).size(60, 40).padRight(-30).padTop(-20);
```

With this padding hack you have the problem, that the button will be outside of your Dialog, and by default, Window checks the bounds of your window when it performs `Actor.hit(...)` evaluation.

We need to disable clipping for that reason, but the rendering of the window depends on it. That's why we use another hack to enable it, just for the rendering:

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    setClip(true);
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    setClip(false);
}
```

Comment: Actually you are wrong about `setClip()` hack. What you need is to `setClip(false)` once, but `setTransform(true)`, as the `Table` drawing does not depend on clipping but have to ensure that internal components are using proper coordinate system, controlled by `transform` variable of the `Group` class.

Comment: You might be right, but keeping clipping enabled for the rendering still seems to be a better solution than disabling it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
private Stage stage;
private Window window; 
private Table table; 
@Override 
public void show() { 
      table = new Table(); 
      table.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 
      , Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 5); 
      window = new Window("", skin); 
      window.setSize(table.getWidth(), table.getHeight()); 

      Button btnWindow = new Button(skin, "close"); 
      btnWindow.addListener(new ClickListener() { 
      @Override 
      public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) { 
             window.setVisible(false); 
         } 
      }); 
      window.addActor(btnWindow); 
      btnWindow.setSize(50, 50); 
      btnWindow.setPosition(window.getWidth() - btnWindow.getWidth() 
      , window.getHeight() - btnWindow.getHeight()); 

      table.addActor(window); 

      window.setModal(true); 
      table.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - window.getWidth() / 2 
                    , Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - window.getHeight() / 2 + 
     100); 
            window.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.alpha(0) 
                    , Actions.fadeIn(.1f) 
                    , Actions.moveTo(+50, +50, 1))); 
     stage.addActor(table); 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. After a bit of searching [this](https://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=11915) thread helped me.

Basically to tell the alignment of the actors inside a table, and to tell the alignment of the table itself are two separate things. Setting the alignment of the table top top-left would produce the desired behavior.

```java
        table = new Table();
        table.setFillParent(true);
        table.setSkin(usedSkin);
        table.setDebug(true);
        table.top().left();

        stage.addActor(table);
        table.add(exitBtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you prepare the dialogbox background with extra spaces with alpha 0 so that, the top corner is actually the centre point of your exit button..