# Close Dialog by clicking outside of it

Tags: java, user-interface, dialog, libgdx

Working with libGDX, and in this particular project we are using `Dialog` to have a box popup when the user clicks a certain button.

What I want is to be able to dismiss the `Dialog` by clicking outside of it.

At other times, I have used two tables, a background table and a menu table, and added a transparent background to the background table that when clicked will remove both of those tables from the `Stage`.

I have tried making a class that has a both a `Dialog` and a background table like the one mentioned above, but the background table never receives any actions.

I have also tried simply adding this background table to the stage before creating the dialog box, but this does not work either.

Finally, I have also tried to subclass `Dialog`, the idea being to override the `show(stage)` method to change its behavior, but I don't know how to do this one, and I'm not sure if it would work, anyway.

I believe the problem is that `dialog.show(stage)` changes the situation in the stage to only accept clicks inside the `Window` of the dialog box. I have seen this question about [adding a close button to a dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29771114/1497671), but playing with the clipping settings is not working to fix this problem.

There is also the possibility that when `show()` calls the `pack()` method and does its layout thing that something is happening that is making what I am trying to do impossible. I think that the solution will be overriding `show()` or overriding `pack()`, or both, but I don't know how to do this.

I can post code if need be, but this should be a pretty complete description of what I have tried and what I need to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but for those like me that searched the entire web for an answer only to find it inside libGDX code, the answer to .close() a libGDX dialog by code is simply to call the method

```
dialog.hide();
```

EDIT (added from the comments below):

> so all he needs to do is register a global touch down event and see if
>   the touch has happened inside the Rectangle of his dialog, if not,
>   close it

Comment: Please, add more explanations to your answer.

Comment: I am simply stating that to close a dialog via code, you can do a dialog.hide(); so all he needs to do is register a global touch down event and see if the touch has happened inside the Rectangle of his dialog, if not, close it :3

Comment: It's better to add these details to the answer.